# Subscribe to Email alerts using HTML and Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a requirement to implement **Subscribe for Email Alerts**. In the home page of my site, I have a email input box and on clicking the subscribe button, the email contact should be added to the subcribers list in the Email Contacts of Gmail. So what approach should I use exactly here?? Or should I use any other language for doing this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't give write access to your Google Contacts to anybody who visits your website, and you shouldn't run a mailing list service without confirmed opt-in and unsubscribe features.

Use software designed for running mailing lists (such as Mailman) or find a third party mailing list management service.

Comment: Can u pls say me abt how to use third party mailing list for my requirement??

Comment: 1. Pick one. 2. Read their instructions.